# Why Firefox asked would you like to remember the password for a non password textbox?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, firefox

I am developing an ASP.Net 4.0 application. On one web form, there are many input boxes.

One of the input box has the following

```
<asp:TextBox ID="InputStu1LastName" runat="server"   OnTextChanged="InputStu1LastName_TextChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" AutoCompleteType="None"  TextMode="SingleLine"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

I deployed this to the web server residing on my machine, so other can do testing before deployment.

When I click the submit button, the Firefox always asked me

"Would you like to remember password abcd on this machine,?"

abcd is actually the input value I input on InputStu1LastName field

I understand the default TextMode for textbox is SingleLine. Orginally, I did not even have that one. Since Firefox keeps thinking it is a password textbox, so I added this atrirbute, and I still got this message.

I used the firebug to troubleshoot, and I could not find anything. The inspector indicator that is just another regular textbox, but not password input field
I even changed the code to like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="InputStu1LastName" runat="server"   ></asp:TextBox>
```

I still get the message

This is the only text field that Firefox believes it is a password field

I have other fields such as InputStu2LastName, InputStu3LastName, etc. The funny thing they are all cloned from InputStu1LastName

Also when my boss test my application on his machine use Chrome, it pre-populated with user name. Chrome thinks that field is a user name field

Any trick to help troubleshoot the problem?

Thank you for any tips.

This is the html markup after rendering

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$InputStu1LastName" maxlength="50" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$InputStu1LastName\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_InputStu1LastName" class="validate[required]" type="text">
```

Like I said before, I have done a lot thing such as removing the class name, event, and maxlength, and nothing works

Also other fields that are cloned from this field does not have the problem.

Comment: Can you post HTML markup of how that field is actually rendered in the browser?

Comment: Thanks. Just a hint: in order for any code (HTML/C#/JS etc.) to appear correctly in your post - select it and click "{ }" icon in the toolbar.

Comment: I know its not an answer but delete the offending textbox, clone one that works in its place and see if that fixes the issue. I have had something similar which just went against all possible reasoning and just recreating the control fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks Mych. Based on your experience, do you think I have to rename the control. Or I just have to delete the control and recreate. Anyway, I will give a try

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is not in this textbox at all.
What Firefox says when it detects a username/pass in the form is something like this:

> Would you like to remember the password for "userName" on http://...

So, most probably you have in your form a textbox which renders html like:

```
<input id="tbpwd" type="password" >
```

It must be located right after the above mentioned "InputStu1LastName", thus fooling Firefox to think it contains a username. In codebehind it will have

```
TextMode="Password"
```

To prevent Firefox trying to be useful in this case, add an atribute:

```
 AutoCompleteType="Disabled"
```

to the problematic textbox in codebehind.